OpenSSL.SSL.Error: [('SSL routines', '', 'wrong version number')]
I'm following this tutorial to create an SQL server proxy: https://github.com/defragmentator/mitmsqlproxy.git.
When I try it with AzureSQL server on AWS, the client(dbeaver) connects successfully, and the proxy logs all the packets exchanged. But if I try it with AzureSQL server on Microsoft SQL, it fails with SSL Routine: wrong version number at do_handshake() https://github.com/defragmentator/mitmsqlproxy/blob/303565d3ff150912e8d5ac72962307bb826eb520/mitmsqlproxy.py#L476C5-L505C1.
PS: I modified bio_write to take full data and not data[8:] as in the original code.
def dataReceived(self, data):
        if self.tls_enabled:
            if self.tls_finished == False:
                LOG.debug("server side: TLS handshake receive")
                self.tls.bio_write(data)
                try:
                   self.tls.do_handshake()
                except SSL.WantReadError:
                    LOG.debug("server side: TLS continue sending handshake")
                    data2 = self.tls.bio_read(TLS_PACKET_SIZE)
                    handshake_req = tds.TDSPacket()
                    handshake_req['Type'] = tds.TDS_PRE_LOGIN
                    handshake_req['Data'] = data2
                    self.transport.write(handshake_req.getData())
                    return
                self.tls_finished = True
                LOG.debug("server side: TLS handshake finished")
                if self.tdsLoginCache != None:
                    LOG.debug("sending cached TDSLogin from client to server")
                    self.write(self.tdsLoginCache)
                return
            else:
                self.tls.bio_write(data)
                data=b''
                while True:
                    try:
                        data=data+self.tls.read(TLS_PACKET_SIZE)
                    except SSL.WantReadError:
                        break



I have tried several versions of pyopenssl, and impacket. I have tried closing and connecting with ConnectSSL but nothing has worked. I also opened an issue but no response yet.
Please has anyone used this or know what might be causing the SSL wrong version number? The full code is in the link provided.

Your question is missing the full error message and the code line where it occurs.

"SSL wrong version number" is most times a misleading error message. It happens often if the peer does not speak SSL at all or does not speak SSL from start (like with SMTP STARTTLS). In this case a non-SSL response will be wrongly interpreted as SSL and bytes 1+2 of the response will be wrongly interpreted of the SSL version field in TLS record layer - leading to this confusing error message.

the error message is SSL Routine: wrong version number, and is happening at the do_handshake() method https://github.com/defragmentator/mitmsqlproxy/blob/303565d3ff150912e8d5ac72962307bb826eb520/mitmsqlproxy.py#L476C5-L505C1
I have updated the question with the link

Azure probably runs the newest tds version which uses ssl from the start, which i'm guessing is not possible to proxy properly, but i could be wrong
